# How to create exported constant with initializer using Typescript AST?

Tags: typescript, typescript-compiler-api

Briefly:

```
export const abc = 123;
```

How to generate such expression using AST?

With this code

```
  return ts.createPropertySignature(
    [ts.createToken(ts.SyntaxKind.ExportKeyword), ts.createToken(ts.SyntaxKind.ConstKeyword)],
    "abc",
    undefined,
    undefined,
    undefined //initializer
  );
```

I've got only

```
export const abc;
```

No idea how to make initializer. No documentation. Google useless.

Comment: This is not a good question as is. You do not have a specific question! What have you tried so far? Where specifically are you stuck? We are not a code-writing service, but rather a help forum

Comment: @PatrickHollweck It's pretty specific. The code with `ts.createPropertySignature` is what he tried, he expected `export const abc = 123;` he got `export const abc;`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think you are creating the correct nodes for what you are trying to achieve. A property signature node is created as part of an interface. For example this would create a property signature:

```
declare interface T {
  prop: number // props signature for node
}
```

If you want to create an exported variable you will need to create a variable statement with a declaration list.

```
ts.createVariableStatement(ts.createModifiersFromModifierFlags(ts.ModifierFlags.Export),
    ts.createVariableDeclarationList([
        ts.createVariableDeclaration("abc", undefined, ts.createLiteral(5))
]))
```

**Note** How do I know this? Simple, there is an AST visualizer that can help you find out what nodes are generated for a piece of code. [See here](https://astexplorer.net/#/gist/a554349d3234afff2154a4b0b735a25e/latest)